# How do I resolve "No protocol specified, error: can't display: :0."?

Tags: linux, terminal, gui, chrome-os

have installed ChromeOS Flex on my PC. It runs great, and I have turned on and installed Linux via the Developer menu in Settings.

But, I cannot run installed Linux applications. When I open them via the Linux apps folder in the "start menu", they just appear to load forever.

If I try to run them via Terminal:

`sudo su ./rider.sh`

they just show an error that says:

```
jase@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads/JetBrains Rider-2023.1.2/bin$ sudo sh ./rider.sh
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

And it doesn't matter which Linux app I try to run, they all display the same error.

How can this be resolved?

I've spent a day or two researching this error and not a single thing I've tried has resolved the issue. I can't even remember everything I've tried.

One of the things suggested was: `xhost +`

But that didn't work either.

Comment: It doesn't work only under `sudo`, or under your regular account as well? Do you have a `DISPLAY` environment variable set? Are there any GUI application installed that you can try starting (for instance, `xterm`) *without* `sudo`?

Comment: @aviro when I `echo $DISPLAY` it says `:0`

Comment: No I can't even use xterm after installing it. Same error.

Comment: I managed to get RealDraw5.exe working under wine by setting `export DISPLAY=:1`, but the scaling is so huge.

Comment: But other apps (not under wine) still aren't working for the same reason.